# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always return null when i trying login using Facebook or Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a problem with `OWIN` Authentication. I always receive null value from `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` when I trying log in using Facebook or Google.

**BUT there is some mystical case.. When I open Fiddler. I get correct data using this method.**

I can't get the reason

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: seems the same problem http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/774138/Default-Oath-authentication-system-doesnt-work-in

Comment: Can you confirm if this behaviour is inside ExternalLoginCallback method?

Comment: @Bilal I have this issue and yes it is inside that method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding this code

```
context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

in the class:

```
    private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            // this line fixed the problem with returing null
            context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

It fixed my problem with returning `NULL`.

Notice: don't use fiddler when logging with twitter authorization. You will receive error.

Comment: Please refer to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180562/mvc5-null-reference-with-facebook-login/20948631#20948631