# Can't get facebook login to work on MVC5. It's always returning NULL on GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, visual-studio-2013, owin

I've been scratching my head and googling all night but nothing seems to be working for me. When trying to login to my mvc5 app using Facebook i keep on getting a null reference error in AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(). Logging in using Google works perfectly.

Here's my setup:

1. Site is running on IIS Express (also tried Local IIS).
2. Already tried both http and https as some articles are saying fb requires SSL. So i'm sticking with `https://localhost:44302/` at the moment (Note: Google works fine either way).

Note: I am using the default setup/templates in mvc5, didn't change anything - except the AppId and AppSecret for fb of course.

Can anyone throw in some solutions pls. Thanks.

Comment: are you set facebook AppId and AppSecret for your app?

Comment: Yes @Yehia , I can actually get to the fb login screen. The error happens on callback.

Comment: I had same problem here. I think it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402008/getexternallogininfoasync-always-return-null-when-i-trying-login-using-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

by this code:

```
var result = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
if (result == null || result.Identity == null)//here will check if user login done
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
if (idClaim == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

var login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value);//here getting login info
var name = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", "");//here getting user name
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Yehia , this worked for me. I also replaced that code in ExternalLoginConfirmation. No more errors, definitely logging in now. It's not returning fb username though, but I'm sure  i can find something tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: urw @DuncanMcIntyre,this link mybe helping you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937553/get-extradata-from-mvc5-framework-oauth-owin-identity-provider-with-external-aut