# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() loginInfo return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I've created a new MVC5 Web Application, and when I try to login with Google by following the official guide http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on, the method function GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns null:

```
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); => NULL
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
```

I know there are a lot of on this subjetct and I tried all the exposed solution like 
[GetExternalLoginInfoAsync null with OWIN in ExternalLoginCallback unless already logged into google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742086/getexternallogininfoasync-null-with-owin-in-externallogincallback-unless-already) or [OWIN's GetExternalLoginInfoAsync Always Returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775321/owins-getexternallogininfoasync-always-returns-null?answertab=votes#) but with no success.

The Google+ API is active and I settup correctly the cliend ID et the Client secret.

*PS: sorry for my english*

Comment: Sorry for the post, i think i find the solution. Actually, this is the proxy of my company which seems to block the callback..

Answer (score -3):

Generally, you must checked settings for hosting company. They impose restricted limits for authentication mechanism same OAuth way. In control panel search "unlock API call..." for example and follow the istructions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).