# ASP Identity GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, asp.net-identity, owin

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

loginInfo is always null, I check the response with fiddler and it seems the site (Steam) return the correct value

```
"response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198057961078",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "Press \"R\" to restart™",
                "lastlogoff": 1435947642,
                "commentpermission": 2,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/warheat1990/",
                "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/59/598fa035b19342a9e0b26a8115e8ddc5da0cc900.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/59/598fa035b19342a9e0b26a8115e8ddc5da0cc900_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/59/598fa035b19342a9e0b26a8115e8ddc5da0cc900_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 1,
                "primaryclanid": "103582791434936111",
                "timecreated": 1327988764,
                "personastateflags": 0
            }
        ]

    }
```

so why am I getting null? I read bunch of thread from people with same problem in SO but no luck so far.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OWIN's GetExternalLoginInfoAsync Always Returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775321/owins-getexternallogininfoasync-always-returns-null)

Comment: like I said, already read that before I post this thread, doesn't help with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason I'm getting null is because I put `app.UseSteamAuthentication("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");` before `app.CreatePerOwinContext` in `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSteamAuthentication("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"); //if you put it here, it won't work
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    //rest of the code here
}
```

so I change it to :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    //rest of the code here
    app.UseSteamAuthentication("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"); //works!
}
```

Comment: if we are using DI (Ninject) we need to do the same thing? or in this case the instance creation of ApplicationDbContext is responsibility of the DI container? @warheat1990