# ACS with Google provider: error 500

Tags: sharepoint, google-oauth, azure-acs

I keep getting same error while trying to login with my Google account to Sharepoint through ACS.

I followed this tutorial: "http://www.fusecollaboration.com/blog/using-google-to-authenticate-with-sharepoint-2013".

The error message I'm getting:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXUx.png)

It's not really useful, does anybody have some experience with this error?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I've tried creating google credentials again, different access control namespace, different sharepoint server - same error.

Comment: Error message appears after authenticating with Google, it redirects to ACS and breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to enable Google+ API. This is the post that helped: [OWIN's GetExternalLoginInfoAsync Always Returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775321/owins-getexternallogininfoasync-always-returns-null/29921451#29921451).