# ASP.NET Web API Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, facebook-login

I have ASP.NET 5 project and I am using Web API to establish the external login (for Facebook and Google). In my case, I have Web API controller (Not MVC controller) which contains the following code :

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
{
    if (error != null)
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);

    var exLog = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

when the mobile application calling this method, I am getting the request authenticated correctly and the property `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true, and I can see in the debugger, that the user is correct, but the problem is the `exlog` variable is always coming null.

here is the `Authentication` property

```
private IAuthenticationManager Authentication => this.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

I read every question on the stack about this bug, but nothing helped me, most of the questions are for the MVC controller, so that did not help.

for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269783/) did not help me because it is for MVC.

**Update**
 I am using Owin 4.0

Comment: I'll add this as a comment to start with as it might not be relevant. I had an issue in the past where the `Auth..` data wasn't available on the returning request but simply redirecting to a `AuthBounce` Action (e.g. `return Redirect("~/AuthBounce");` _then_ trying to access `var exLog = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` worked. Give that a try. I appreciate this might not be _exactly_ the same as your setup looks a little different.

Comment: where should I put `return Redirect("~/AuthBounce");` ?

Comment: remove the current `var exLog = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` and replace it with the redirect. On your new `AuthBounce` action add in the `var exLog = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` and see if it is no longer null. Like I say, this might not be relevant/work but worth a try

Comment: @scgough thank you I tried it but did not work

Comment: **Important after putting this question and start a bounty for it, I discovered that I do not need to call this method at all and my problem was solved, it was completely related to another thing, then this problem, Sorry for Inconvenience**

Comment: @HakamFostok : Do you mind posting the solution here?

Comment: @HakamFostok Please post the solution

Comment: @user1431866 Actually I changed my way completely, The solution for me that I should not call this method in the first place. According to my situation, I should not call this method at all.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who asked me in the comments to put my answer.
Actually, the problem has not been solved and I did not find a solution for this, 
 I am sorry to say that.

What I discovered is that I do not need to call this method from the beginning. 
 and I went completely another way (I do not remember how and why)

Just small advice: consider the situation again and reconsider if you really need to call this method.

I wish I had been more helpful, I am sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting "NULL" because you didn't write the code if the IsAuthenticated = true then what should it do? (means redirection to any page or else).

see carefully your if condition for IsAuthenticated:
if (**!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**)

May be this can help you.

Comment: no this has no relation to my problem at all. by the way, the problem solved, and I am not using this method any more.

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable Google + API in the Google console. Also make sure the secret key is not concatenated with a space at the end after you paste it to your code.