# Microsoft authentication no longer works on ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

We've been developing a social platform with my team and we faced with a strange issue today.

People can only login and register using their college email and we use Microsoft API to authorize their requests.

In the register screen, they enter profile information and when they click "Register" the code below triggers:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                string userName = TruncateEmail(Input.Email);

                ...
            }
}
```

For the past weeks, `var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` worked just fine. But today the function started returning null, meaning that registration system is not working anymore.

I searched on the internet and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269783/authenticationmanager-getexternallogininfoasync-on-google-aspnet-mvc5-returns) question asked here on StackOverflow. They solved their issue by updating the NuGet packages to latest versions. When I checked mine, all .NET packages have updates from v6 to v7. So I updated the project from .NET 6 to .NET 7 and updated all other Microsoft packages.

Well, it's still not working. The function keeps returning null.

Comment: Have you checked for any changes in your code for how the identity is setup and registered in the DI?

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, no changes were made for identity setup and registration lately.

Answer (score 1):

As a novice in asp.net core authentication, I also encountered the same problem as the original author in my self-practice project, but I successfully solved it. I am not sure whether I can solve the original author's problem well.
But as a feasible solution, let’s make this record

First, [the official document of asp.net core does not clearly indicate the need to use cookie auth](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46743#issuecomment-1438866347), which is also the key point.

You need to add this cookie auth snippet to your `Program.cs`. But I think [this snippet of this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configuration) is better than the first link inside the previous one.

I think the document is good, but if you don't have any knowledge or experience in authentication, then you will have trouble with implementation.